# Why is casting a string to DATETIME not accurate to the ms?

Tags: sql-server

Why does

```
SELECT CAST('2014-11-28 15:06:02.165' AS DATETIME)
```

return:

```
2014-11-28 15:06:02.167
```

Comment: [Why is SQL Server losing a millisecond?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715432/why-is-sql-server-losing-a-millisecond)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DateTime` has a precision of has a  0.00333(1/300th) seconds, so sql server rounds value to nearest 1/300th.

If you are using SQL Server 2008 above, use [DateTime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) which can have a precision of millisecond, even down to 100 nanoseconds and can hold the accurate value.

```
SELECT CAST('2014-11-28 15:06:02.165' AS DATETIME2(3));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a little surprising. I would never have expected the value to change between string and DATETIME. I wouldn't be surprised if it has messed up a few systems.

Comment: @Dmaien, it's not changed, but truncated to match the datatype accuracy. If you had cast the string to `DATE`, would you expect the hours and minutes to remain?

Comment: @DamienGolding what would you expect `SELECT CAST('3.6666666666666666' AS float)` to return?

Comment: @ypercube Obviously I would expect truncation to happen with DATE but the confusing thing with DATETIME is that it returns ms in a format down to 1 ms but can't represent them all. Does it have a practical purpose? In other words, why not limit to 0.01s?